# Can not get the clip-path to work for my logo

Tags: jquery, css, animation, svg

I want to animate my company logo to look like as it is being written. I have the original SVG with the logo paths and created separate paths that will function as the mask which will be animated.

For some reason the mask is not covering the original logo whilst if you show the mask path, it should be covering the logo.

Can anyone help me out?

My code so far is on CodePen here: http://codepen.io/MRSYDSTER/pen/XpWwdB

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Grip Dashing</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    </style>
</head>


<body>
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 16;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <path id="r" clip-path="url(#myClip)" fill="#44A647" d="M7.066,8.727L7.001,8.29H6.476v2.617H7.13V9.301c0.251-0.308,0.397-0.453,0.564-0.453
                        c0.076,0,0.22,0.02,0.276,0.04L8.045,8.27C7.955,8.244,7.869,8.232,7.743,8.232C7.474,8.232,7.313,8.385,7.066,8.727z"/>
                    <polygon id="i" clip-path="url(#myClip)" fill="#44A647" points="8.539,8.794 8.941,8.794 8.941,10.907 9.596,10.907 9.596,8.29 8.539,8.29     "/>
                    <path id="gp" clip-path="url(#myClip)" fill="#44A647" d="M11.56,5.534c-0.37,0-0.748,0.061-1.13,0.181c-0.384-1.318-1.596-2.245-2.996-2.245
                        c-1.403,0-2.629,0.94-3.004,2.271C4.34,5.735,4.251,5.731,4.161,5.731c-1.896,0-3.438,1.542-3.438,3.438
                        c0,0.865,0.322,1.692,0.909,2.329c0.448,0.484,0.941,0.808,1.531,0.966c0.093,0.025,0.337,0.078,0.579,0.113
                        c0.221,0.032,0.439,0.046,0.525,0.052c0.094,0.005,0.185,0.008,0.269,0.008c0.89,0,1.337-0.354,1.337-1.181V8.418
                        C5.42,8.292,5.107,8.246,4.786,8.246c-0.965,0-1.415,0.611-1.415,1.42c0,0.691,0.327,1.252,1.073,1.252
                        c0.302,0,0.522-0.106,0.774-0.318v0.947c0,0.45-0.213,0.576-0.707,0.576c-0.253,0-0.531-0.015-0.764-0.044
                        c-1.194-0.121-2.472-1.426-2.472-2.908c0-1.591,1.293-2.885,2.885-2.885c0.571,0,1.125,0.167,1.598,0.483
                        c0.126,0.085,0.298,0.051,0.383-0.076c0.084-0.128,0.051-0.299-0.077-0.385c-0.333-0.222-0.7-0.382-1.084-0.475
                        c0.327-1.062,1.319-1.807,2.452-1.807c1.169,0,2.18,0.786,2.478,1.896C9.46,6.162,9.149,6.55,8.996,6.933
                        c-0.062,0.153-0.13,0.525-0.133,0.568C8.862,7.512,8.862,7.523,8.862,7.534c0,0.233,0.167,0.389,0.399,0.389
                        c0.233,0,0.398-0.156,0.398-0.389c0-0.148-0.067-0.264-0.174-0.329c0.109-0.331,0.414-0.701,0.847-0.871
                        c0.002,0,0.003-0.001,0.004-0.002c0.418-0.163,0.829-0.246,1.224-0.246c1.744,0,3.164,1.419,3.164,3.164
                        c0,1.605-1.009,2.95-2.6,3.136c-0.232,0.029-0.507,0.046-0.759,0.046c-0.496,0-0.711-0.126-0.711-0.577V11.57v-0.637
                        c0.151,0.03,0.333,0.056,0.509,0.056c0.919,0,1.344-0.648,1.344-1.455c0-0.703-0.325-1.263-1.058-1.263
                        c-0.383,0-0.64,0.152-0.882,0.409l-0.051-0.34H9.999v3.23v0.196c0,0.828,0.45,1.181,1.338,1.181c0.248,0,0.556-0.025,0.809-0.076
                        c1.87-0.219,3.131-1.734,3.131-3.62C15.277,7.202,13.609,5.534,11.56,5.534z M4.582,10.393c-0.404,0-0.524-0.353-0.524-0.793
                        c0-0.529,0.24-0.847,0.68-0.847c0.181,0,0.33,0.04,0.481,0.1v1.197C5.017,10.276,4.82,10.393,4.582,10.393z M10.653,9.18
                        c0.25-0.262,0.423-0.383,0.655-0.383c0.379,0,0.505,0.353,0.505,0.813c0,0.555-0.222,0.864-0.661,0.864
                        c-0.207,0-0.348-0.051-0.499-0.111V9.18z"/>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="myClip">
          <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.85" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M10.5,8.9c0.6-0.2,1.7-0.8,1.7,0.8
                c0,0.8-0.6,0.9-1.6,1"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.85" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M9.4,8c-0.6-1.5,1.1-2.2,2.1-2.2
                c2.4,0.1,3.2,1.6,3.5,3.3c0.4,2.7-3.3,4.1-4.2,3.5c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.7-0.6-1.7c0-1.2,0.2-1.1-0.1-2.7"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.85" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M8.5,8.5c0.5,0,0.7,0.1,0.8,0.1
                s-0.1,1.3,0,2.4"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M6.9,9.1c0.4-0.2,0.9-0.5,1.3-0.7"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M6.8,11c-0.1-0.9-0.2-1.9-0.3-2.8"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M4.7,5.8c0.2-1.3,1.5-2.1,2.8-2.1s2.2,0.9,2.7,2.1"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M5.2,10.3c-0.5,0-0.8,0.4-1.1,0.1c-0.4-0.3-0.4-1-0.2-1.4
                c0.4-0.7,1.4-0.7,1.7-0.4c0.1,0.1,0,0.3,0,0.3c0,1.3,0,2.6,0,2.7c-0.3,0.8-1.8,0.7-2.7,0.4c-1.3-0.5-2.2-2.2-1.8-3.8
                c0.4-1.5,2-2.2,3.3-2.1c1.1,0.1,1.5,0.4,1.7,0.7"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>

<script>
var paths = $(‘path:not(defs path)’);

paths.each(function(i, e) {
    e.style.strokeDasharray = e.style.strokeDashoffset = e.getTotalLength();
});

var tl = new TimelineMax();

tl.add([
    TweenLite.to(paths.eq(0), 1, {strokeDashoffset: 0, delay: 0.0}),
    TweenLite.to(paths.eq(1), 1, {strokeDashoffset: 0, delay: 0.5}),
]);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extracted the clip path from your SVG and ended up with this:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="200" height="200">
  <g fill="#000" fill-opacity="0.2" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.05">
    <path d="M10.5,8.9c0.6-0.2,1.7-0.8,1.7,0.8c0,0.8-0.6,0.9-1.6,1" />
    <path d="M9.4,8c-0.6-1.5,1.1-2.2,2.1-2.2c2.4,0.1,3.2,1.6,3.5,3.3
     c0.4,2.7-3.3,4.1-4.2,3.5c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.7-0.6-1.7c0-1.2,0.2-1.1
     -0.1-2.7" />
    <path d="M8.5,8.5c0.5,0,0.7,0.1,0.8,0.1s-0.1,1.3,0,2.4" />
    <path d="M6.9,9.1c0.4-0.2,0.9-0.5,1.3-0.7" />
    <path d="M6.8,11c-0.1-0.9-0.2-1.9-0.3-2.8" />
    <path d="M4.7,5.8c0.2-1.3,1.5-2.1,2.8-2.1s2.2,0.9,2.7,2.1" />
    <path d="M5.2,10.3c-0.5,0-0.8,0.4-1.1,0.1c-0.4-0.3-0.4-1-0.2-1.4
     c0.4-0.7,1.4-0.7,1.7-0.4c0.1,0.1,0,0.3,0,0.3c0,1.3,0,2.6,0,
     2.7c-0.3,0.8-1.8,0.7-2.7,0.4c-1.3-0.5-2.2-2.2-1.8-3.8c0.4-1.5,
     2-2.2,3.3-2.1c1.1,0.1,1.5,0.4,1.7,0.7" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

It looks like you were expecting the stroke parts of this clipping path to be included in the masked area. I'm afraid that isn't how clipping paths work. [As per the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath),

> *The raw geometry of each child element exclusive of rendering properties such as ‘fill’, ‘stroke’, ‘stroke-width’ within a ‘clipPath’ conceptually defines a 1-bit mask (with the possible exception of anti-aliasing along the edge of the geometry) which represents the silhouette of the graphics associated with that element. Anything outside the outline of the object is masked out.*

Basically, the `stroke-width` attributes in your clipping path have no effect at all. You have to expand them into filled regions if you want them to do anything useful.

Alternatively, convert the logo into a set of stroked paths with no fills. This will change its appearance slightly, but will get you closer to the effect you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Or use a mask instead of a clipPath. In a mask, the stroke colour and size *does* contribute.